# When is proof by contradiction necessary?

Tags: soft-question

Is there a way to test a given statement can't be proved directly?

Thanks.

Comment: If such a test existed, then a great part of [constructivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) would be easy...

Answer (score 0):

Often a proof by contradiction is the easiest path. But those proofs are hard to understand, and offer little or no insight into the "why" the statement is true, so it is often recommended to use it as last resort.